# How to select a part of a string from a beginning index to the very end in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

```
string = "Yellow"
puts string[1..string.length] -> outputs "ellow"
```

Is there a shorter way to get Ruby to do the same thing without using string.length? In Python, for example, we can write string[1:] and it will do it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While using `[]` in Ruby to get the index of a String or an Array, using a negative number will start the counting from the end of the index starting with `1` (`[-0]` will get you the same as `[0]`).

In your example,

```
puts string[1..-1]
```

will output the desired string `"ellow"`. 
Equally,

```
puts string[1..-2]
```

will produce `"ello"` and so on.

[Documentation for String#[]](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-5B-5D)

Answer (score 2):

You should use -1 as right boundary in your interval:

```
string = "Yellow"
puts string[1..-1] -> outputs "ellow"
```